# Not able to resolve the "NullPointerException"

Tags: java

Am actually trying to get the hashmap value by using `get(Object key)` function.
But the below code is throwing `NullPointerException` at line

```
 count+=hm.get((int)str.charAt(i));
```

So please help me to fix it.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     String str = String.valueOf(br.readLine());
     HashMap<Integer,Integer> hm =new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
     hm.put(0, 6);
     hm.put(1, 2);
     hm.put(2, 5);
     hm.put(3, 5);
     hm.put(4, 4);
     hm.put(5, 5);
     hm.put(6, 6);
     hm.put(7, 3);
     hm.put(8, 7);
     hm.put(9, 6);
long count=0;

//System.out.println(hm.get(9));
     for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
     {

         count+=hm.get((int)str.charAt(i));
     }
     System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: what is `str`? Please clarify

Comment: str is a variable of type String, am reading the input into String str.

Comment: input is a string of digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you cast the `char` that the `charAt` method returns to `int` you get the Unicode code point for the character. For example `(int)'1'` will give you 49, but your map does not have an entry for 49.

To solve this you could define the mapping as `HashMap<Character, Integer>`, or use [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue-char-) instead of casting to int.

```
hm.get(Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of the type casting declare a map as

```
HashMap<Character,Integer> hm =new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
hm.put('0', 6);
hm.put('1', 2);
hm.put('2', 5);
.....
long count=0;

for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
     count+=hm.get(str.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following code is a better choice

firstly you should check that the expression  `str.charAt(i)` can be as a digit. then the digit should exists in the `hashmap`

```
char ch = str.charAt(i);
if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
    if (hm.containsKey(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch)))) {
        count+=hm.get(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(ch)));
    }
}
```

hope that helped

Comment: Yes definitely helped, but i don't get what is causing the error "NullpointerException" because according to my understanding, that exception occurs when the object reference  points to null, So could you tell which reference is pointing to null in my code?